# Play framework Missing Controller

Tags: java, scala, playframework, sbt

I'm having a problem where the play framework just reports a "Missing Controller" even after I have created it.

> [error] {file:/my/path/to/project/root/}Project Name/compile:sources: PlayException: Compilation error [Missing Controller]
>   [error] Total time: 0 s, completed 26-Mar-2012 13:12:22

(I have removed the project name and file path)

Here is the relevant code

```
package controllers;

import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;

public class cron extends Controller {

    private static Logger logger = java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("uk.itvet.portal.CDR.CronJob");

    public static Result run() {
        return ok("Working");
    }
}
```

I have created a line in the routes config for the page

```
GET     /cron                       controllers.cron.run()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe a case issue ? Try renaming the controller in `Cron` instead of `cron`.

Comment: creating a function like the one below inside the initial Application class seems to work  `public static Result runCron() { return cron.run();}`

Comment: Maybe `run` is a reserved method somewhere (but I cannot find it in the documentation : http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0/java/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### for Play framework 1.0

1. rename the class "cron" to "Cron"
2. in run() method change return type to "void"
3. in router file replace line by:

> GET     /cron                       Cron.run()